# Issue in generating noise and euclidean distance

Tags: matlab, noise, euclidean-distance

(a) How do I generate noise such that the maximum levels of the added noise correspond with 3.9% to 50% of the average absolute deviation.

(b) How do I generate white Gaussian noise and uniform noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only help with b)

Uniform noise (according to wikipedia) only has a uniform distribution, which should make it white as well):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise#Quantization_noise_.28uniform_noise.29

```
uni_noise = rand(100000,1); % uniform noise
hist(uni_noise,500) % uniform distribution
pwelch(uni_noise) % also white noise (even power density)
```

Gaussian White noise requires an even power density and a normal distribution:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise

```
gauss_noise = randn(100000,1); % gaussian noise
hist(gauss_noise,500) % gaussian (or normal) distribution (bell curve) + zero mean
pwelch(gauss_noise) % even power density
```

Comment: When SNR=0, does it mean zero amplitude?So, awgn command does not create zero mean gaussian noise as doen by gauss_noise = randn(100000,1); % gaussian noise ? In that case, how do I generate noise for a particular SNR as created by the command awgn?

Comment: My mistake, you are correct.
`plot(x); hold on; plot(awgn(x,0, 'measured'))` shows the noise it is adding.
I've never used the built in noise functions to be honest, and my only experience with noise is for probility distributions for EKFs and regular kalman filters (which are thought of more as vectors than signals so SNR never comes into play). (I'm a Mech/Controls by trade SNR isn't something I deal with very often.)

Comment: Ok, but if you know then could you tell me how to generate noise for specific SNR without using awgn command?

Comment: I think, awgn, is what you are looking for after all.
a) I don't understand where average absolute deviation comes from. Is there a moving avg of std() or something?
c) d) are outside of my scope